# Unexpected token error when using XmlDataSource asp control

Tags: asp.net

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<viewentries timestamp="20100923T130205,90Z" toplevelentries="8903">
   <viewentry position="1" unid="A4958CC88435D1A8422577A7004422E8" noteid="4DF15A" siblings="8903">
      <entrydata columnnumber="0" name="$59">
         <text>63722</text>
      </entrydata>
      <entrydata columnnumber="1" name="$70">
         <text></text>
      </entrydata>
      <entrydata columnnumber="2" name="pt_Subject">
         <text>work order subject</text>
      </entrydata>
      <entrydata columnnumber="3" name="$56">
         <datetime dst="true">20100923T145811,67+02</datetime>
      </entrydata>
      <entrydata columnnumber="4" name="$62">
         <datetime>20100923T142413,84+02</datetime>
      </entrydata>
      <entrydata columnnumber="5" name="$60">
         <text>some company</text>
      </entrydata>
      <entrydata columnnumber="6" name="$73">
         <text>Resolver</text>
      </entrydata>
   </viewentry>
</viewentries>
```

As this XML resides on a web server, I need to read it from there. Thus, I use XmlDataSource control like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>#WO</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Company</td>
    </tr>
<asp:Repeater ID="repWorkOrders" DataSourceID="xmldsWorkOrders" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>           
        <tr>
            <td><%#XPath( "entrydata[1]/text" )%></td>
            <td><%#XPath( "entrydata[3]/text" )%></td>
            <td><%#XPath( "entrydata[6]/text" )%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmldsWorkOrders" XPath="viewentries/viewentry" DataFile="http://www.someurl.com/xmlfile.xml" runat="server">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

The problem is that if I set DataFile to URL, I get following error

> '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1,
>   position 63. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Xml.XmlException: '>' is an
>   unexpected token. The expected token
>   is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 63.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [XmlException: '>' is an unexpected
>   token. The expected token is '"' or
>   '''. Line 1, position 63.]
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception
>   e) +76
>   System.Xml.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.Throw(Exception
>   e) +9
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.Throw(Int32
>   curPos, String res, String[] args)
>   +125    System.Xml.DtdParser.ThrowUnexpectedToken(Int32
>   pos, String expectedToken1, String
>   expectedToken2) +109
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalId(Token
>   idTokenType, Token declType, String&
>   publicId, String& systemId) +598
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean
>   saveInternalSubset) +4016890
>   System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean
>   saveInternalSubset) +54
>   System.Xml.DtdParserProxy.Parse(Boolean
>   saveInternalSubset) +31
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
>   +254    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>   +451    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>   +151    System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument
>   doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace) +112
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader) +108
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource.PopulateXmlDocument(XmlDocument
>   document, CacheDependency&
>   dataCacheDependency, CacheDependency&
>   transformCacheDependency) +306
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument()
>   +153    System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +27
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.GetData()
>   +35    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource) +220
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs
>   e) +51
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.EnsureDataBound()
>   +55    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +80    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

However, if I save the same xml to a file to my computer, it works without a glitch. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check xmlfile.xml Line 1, position 63. Looks like you have missing closing quote in a parameter value

Answer (score 2):

Silly me. The xml is password protected. I just didn't notice it as I logged in early in the morning. Hence, the data source obtains login form instead of xml file.